Why etree.tostring() removes path in svg element
my_code is
<svg width="400em" height="1.08em" viewBox="0 0 400000 1080" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">
    <path d="M95,702
c-2.7,0,-7.17,-2.7,-13.5,-8c-5.8,-5.3,-9.5,-10,-9.5,-14
c0,-2,0.3,-3.3,1,-4c1.3,-2.7,23.83,-20.7,67.5,-54
c44.2,-33.3,65.8,-50.3,66.5,-51c1.3,-1.3,3,-2,5,-2c4.7,0,8.7,3.3,12,10
s173,378,173,378c0.7,0,35.3,-71,104,-213c68.7,-142,137.5,-285,206.5,-429
c69,-144,104.5,-217.7,106.5,-221
l0 -0
c5.3,-9.3,12,-14,20,-14
H400000v40H845.2724
s-225.272,467,-225.272,467s-235,486,-235,486c-2.7,4.7,-9,7,-19,7
c-6,0,-10,-1,-12,-3s-194,-422,-194,-422s-65,47,-65,47z
M834 80h400000v40h-400000z"></path>
</svg>

I am using etree.tostring(my_code, method='html', encoding='unicode')
Why etree removes path element?

What do you mean by "removes path element"? I get the same element in and out.
